# Kill all applications oppened during a session an user

Tags: android, launcher

I'm creating an Android launcher for hardware demonstrations purposes. Let's say some guy click a button and the launcher will allow the user to test the equipment for 5 minutes. After that the launcher will kill all the applications opened by the user, alongside with all user information and history, restoring the device to the original state.

How is the best way to do that ? I know how to create the launcher and to block and unlock the interface for a amount of time, but have no idea about knowing which applications the user used  so I can kill they.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have to return to a known ***clean*** state deleting all the data the user may have entered, not only by killing the apps they may have started.
Rebooting to a know state (**clearing user data**) is your safest bet.

Comment: To do that I will have to make my own custom rom and execute a linux script on shutdown, right ? I know how to that, but the device take some time to restart, and let's say if a convention like CES with thousands of people wanting to test the device is impracticable.